# LINQ IQueryable Query

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my query for retrieving list of inactive/active users from my database. my problem is that, my query seems to be too complicated. so can you please give me a tip how to enhance my query.

here's my code

```
            using (basecampcoreEntities dbs = ConfigAndResource.BaseCampContext())
        {
            //loads all user where isactive property has the same value as IsActive
            var Users = from useritem in dbs.users
                        where useritem.useraccount.IsActive.Equals(IsActive)
                        orderby useritem.useraccount.CreatedDate
                        select useritem;

            //check if users count is greater than 0
            if (Users.Count() > 0)
            {

                List<user> CasebookUser = new List<user>();
                switch (SearchBy)
                {
                    case DTO::SearchBy.FirstName:
                        {
                            CasebookUser = Users.Where(item => item.FirstName.ToUpper().Equals(SearchText.ToUpper())).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
                        } break;
                    case DTO::SearchBy.LastName:
                        {
                            CasebookUser = Users.Where(item => item.LastName.ToUpper().Equals(SearchText.ToUpper())).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
                        } break;
                    case DTO::SearchBy.LoginID:
                        {
                            CasebookUser = Users.Where(item => item.LoginID.ToUpper().Equals(SearchText.ToUpper())).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
                        } break;
                    case DTO::SearchBy.None:
                            CasebookUser = Users.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
                        {
                        } break;
                }

                //transform the data into DTO class
                return (from item in CasebookUser
                        select new DTO::User
                        {
                            LoginID = item.LoginID,
                            FirstName = item.FirstName,
                            LastName = item.LastName,
                            MiddleName = item.MiddleName,
                            Birhtday = item.userinfo != null ? item.userinfo.Birthday : DateTime.UtcNow
                        }).ToList();
            }
            return null;
```

Comment: You are also hitting the DB a couple of times instead of once, unnecessarily.

Comment: do you mean my code in switch?

Comment: use only .ToList when ur model is final.

Comment: You are counting the records and then executing the query resulting in two hits. There's no need for that.

Comment: @TimRogers, i'm using the .count() to check if the result is not null, then i will use my switch case to check if it was search by first name, last name etc. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @VondRitz, i use to .tolist() twice because i declare a variable CasebookUser in list type. is there other way to make it more simple?

Comment: `Users = Users.Where(item => item.FirstName.ToUpper().Equals(SearchText.ToUpper())).Skip(skip).Take(take);`

Comment: and use `.Any`. I think it is much faster.

Comment: @FrancisCebu The result will never be `null`. There may be zero results, but you can handle that after you've executed your query and save a roundtrip to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage the power of delayed execution here...

```
// first filter by whether user is active or not
var query = dbs.users.Where(x => x.useraccount.IsActive == IsActive);    

// next filter by specific search field
switch (SearchBy)
{
    case DTO::SearchBy.FirstName:
    {
        query = query.Where(x => string.Equals(x.FirstName, SearchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)); 
        break;
    }
    case DTO::SearchBy.LastName:
    {
        query = Users.Where(x => string.Equals(x.LastName, SearchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        break;
    }
    ...
}

// then apply paging
query = query.Skip(skip).Take(take);

// finally, order by CreatedDate (ascending)
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.useraccount.CreatedDate);

// now fetch the records!
return (from item in query
        select new DTO::User
        {
            LoginID = item.LoginID,
            FirstName = item.FirstName,
            LastName = item.LastName,
            MiddleName = item.MiddleName,
            Birhtday = item.userinfo != null ? item.userinfo.Birthday : DateTime.UtcNow
         }).ToList();
```

This code will give you what you need in a more optimal way (only 1 DB trip) - and it's a bit more readable into the bargain.

Comment: @FrancisCebu I have added some comments to take you through the code.

Comment: You could potentially break apart the ordering the DTO creation and the database hit too. I think that would make it a even better example for new programmers to Linq2Entites.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Remove the sort from the original query definition
2. Do not convert `ToList()` and to `Skip()' and`Take()` prematurely
3. Do not cast `ToList()` twice. Only do it when you are creating your final collection.
4. Make `IsActive` comparison more clear in the initial query
5. Rewrite first query as one line linq expression
6. Use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`
7. Convert your search text `ToUpper()` just one time. Makes your search cases more concise and readable (same with using == instead of `Equals`)

This code might help:

```
using (basecampcoreEntities dbs = ConfigAndResource.BaseCampContext())
{
  //loads all user where isactive property has the same value as IsActive
  var Users = db.Users.Where(x => x.useraccount.IsActive == IsActive);

  if (Users.Any())
  {
    var searchText = SearchText.ToUpper();
    switch (SearchBy)
    {
      case DTO::SearchBy.FirstName:
        Users = Users.Where(item => item.FirstName.ToUpper() == searchText);
        break;
      case DTO::SearchBy.LastName:
        Users = Users.Where(item => item.LastName.ToUpper() == searchText);
        break;
      case DTO::SearchBy.LoginID:
        Users = Users.Where(item => item.LoginID.ToUpper() == searchText);
        break;
   }

   // apply sort and skip/take
   Users = Users.OrderBy(x => x.useraccount.CreateDate).Skip(skip).Take(take);

   //transform the data into DTO class
   return (from item in Users 
           select new DTO::User
           {
              LoginID = item.LoginID,
              FirstName = item.FirstName,
              LastName = item.LastName,
              MiddleName = item.MiddleName,
              Birthday = item.userinfo != null ? item.userinfo.Birthday : DateTime.UtcNow
           }).ToList();
    }
    return null;
}
```